# How to add a new key to the dictionary that is retrieved from NSUserDefaults in Swfit IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift2, nsuserdefaults

HI below code throws exception when i try to execute . I am trying to add a new key to the existing dictionary that is retrieved from the NSUserDefaults.
ex:

```
    var receivedMachineId = "1"
    var equipment = [receivedMachineId: ["make" : "receivedMake",
        "model" : "receivedModel",
        "machineId" : "receivedMachineId",
        "notes": "receivedNotes",
        "status": "receivedStatus"
        ]
    ]

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(equipment, forKey: "equipment")
    if var retrievedDict = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey("equipment")  {
        var myDict = retrievedDict
        print(myDict)
        print(myDict["1"]!["make"])
        myDict["1"]!["newKey"] = "New Value"

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get the Dictionary. Store it in a variable.
2. Add your new data to that variable.
3. Override the entry for "equipment" with the variable

Example:

```
if let dict = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey("equipment") as? Dictionary<String,Dictionary<String,String>> {
    var myDict = dict
    myDict["new_key"] = "new value"
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myDict, forKey: "equipment")
}
```

Comment: When i try that it is showing an error "Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'AnyObject?!'

Comment: @venkatkotu On what line?

Comment: i am unable to do this var tempDict = NSUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey("equipment") ; tempDict["newKey"] = "Value" or tempDict.setValue["new key"] = "value"

Comment: @venkatkotu Please try my example code. If that doesn't work, tell me what line you get an error on.

Comment: Hi Jones, please see the update code in the question. i see the error right exactly on line myDict["1"]!["newKey"] = "New Value" . please help me

Comment: @venkatkotu Please see my edit. The problem was that you weren't casting the object from NSUserDefaults to any type, so it didn't know how to subscript `AnyObject`. Showing that it's a dictionary will let it know it can subscript it.

Comment: @venkatkotu Did my solution work? If so, please mark this as Best Answer

Answer (score 0):

To add another value to a dictionary:

```
dict["newKey"] = "newValue"
```

Putting it together with NSUserDefaults:

```
var receivedMachineId = "1"

var equipment = [receivedMachineId: [
    "make" : "receivedMake",
    "model" : "receivedModel",
    "machineId" : "receivedMachineId",
    "notes": "receivedNotes",
    "status": "receivedStatus"
    ]
]

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(equipment, forKey: "equipment")

if var retrievedDict = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey("equipment")  {
    print(retrievedDict)
    equipment[receivedMachineId]!["newKey"] = "newValue"
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(equipment, forKey: "equipment")
    NSUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey("equipment") // show dictionary
}
```

Basically you just add your new keys/values to the dictionary and then `setObject` (the modified dictionary) back into NSUserDefaults.